# In Kafka, How to wait for all children message to finish before send out parent message?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic1 with a message Parent, inside this Parent it contains multiple Child messages, let's say Child1...5. These are my topics, for each topic I have a bunch of workers tackling message on that topic.

topic1: Parent_Msg_In
topic2: Child_Msg_In
topic3: Child_Msg_Out
topic4: Parent_Msg_Out

What I want is: wait for all 5 Child messages to complete on Child_Msg_Out topic before reporting the corresponding Parent Message completion on Parent_Msg_Out.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by children? Partition or you have topics inside topics?

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more, requirement is not so clear. About you want all 5 child messages to complete on child_msg_out what do you mean by that?

Comment: I think they want an event when all workers finished their work an a specific message before doing something else.